# react - Why does Parent Component state change when using updating state on Child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, brunch

When I modify state on child components by doing something like this:

```
// inside child component
var stateToSet = this.state;
stateToSet[active] = false;
this.setState(nextState);
```

Parent State changes without rerendering.

I suppose the Parent Component `this.state` is being referenced when `stateToSet[active] = false`, so I `Object.assign`'d the state and each property I want to modify, and then it works without modifying Parent's state.

I would like to now why is this happening. Could this be intended behavior? Could Brunch(my compiler) and concatenating files be the problem?

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post some relevant code from your parent and child components? Are you triggering any callback functions from child to parent? Ideally state change in child component will not affect parent.

Answer (score 0):

Yup so you should never modify the state directly like you're doing here because `this.setState` will actually trigger all the lifecycle methods of your component and modifying state like here will not. That function takes keys you'd like to modify so no need to `Object.assign` or `...`.

```
this.setState({ active: false })
```

I'm not sure what you mean by Parent/child though and why setting the child's parent would have anything to do with the parent's, but if you mean that the parent is not re-rendered when the child's state changes, then that is the intended behavior.

Comment: I simplified the code in the Question, but now it seems like it isn't helping. I need to modify an especific array item with something like `this.setState({ filters[filterIndex] = updatedFilter})` (this doesn't work, it's just for example)

Comment: I dont see any changes in the question. Could you maybe post more code? It's unclear what you're asking as most of the parts are missing.